# How to correctly include and use a function defined in an external C file into a Cpp file?

Tags: c++

`c_file.h` :

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int doubleFunct(int i);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

`c_file.c` :

```
#include <c_file.h>

int doubleFunct(int i)
{
    return 2 * i;
}
```

I included the "C" doubleFunct in the cpp file:

`basic.cc` :

```
#include "iostream"

extern "C" {
    #include "c_file.h"
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int di = doubleFunct(2);
    std::cout << "di: " << di << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But I get `undefined reference to 'doubleFunct'`

```
g++ src/basic.cc -o basic -std=c++17
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccO0NgkQ.o: in function `main':
basic.cc:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `doubleFunct'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How to correctly include and use a function defined in an external C file into a Cpp file?

Comment: On the command line you need to compile both files: `g++ basic.cc c_file.c -o basic`

Comment: `extern "C" {
    #include "c_file.h"
}` This is already done in the header file. Just include it

Comment: @user3386109 and 273K Thank you for your kind helpful suggestions . Third mistake I made: #include <c_file.h> ---> #include "c_file.h

Comment: @user3386109 @273K If I put in `CMakeLists.txt` file : `add_executable(basic src/basic.cc src/c_file.c)`  I still get during building phase : `cmake --build cmakebuilddir/" the error "undefined reference to `doubleFunct'`